# want to insert data in table in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i have table and in first three rows of table is hardcoded,also i have multiple inputs and when i enter data in input and when i clicked on submit button the data from inputs should goes into table row .
here is my code

```
 this.state={
            Id:'',
            Name:'',
            birth:'',
            data:[
                {
                id:'1',
                name:'Muhammad Ali jinnah',
                dateofBirth:'1876'
                },
                {
                    id:'2',
                    name:'Allama Iqbal',
                    dateofBirth:'1877'
                },
                {
                    id:'3',
                    name:'Ahmad Bilal',
                    dateofBirth:'1992'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    this.handleIDChange = this.handleIDChange.bind(this);
    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleBirthChange = this.handleBirthChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
handleIDChange(event) {
    this.setState({Id: event.target.value});
  }
  handleNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({Name: event.target.value});
  }
  handleBirthChange(event) {
    this.setState({birth: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log('A ID:name and birth was submitted: ' + this.state.Id,this.state.Name,this.state.birth);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
 render() {
return (
  <div className="fun3">
    <BootstrapTable data={this.state.data}>
 <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id' headerAlign="left" width="30"tdStyle={ {backgroundColor: ''}}>
          ID
   </TableHeaderColumn>
 <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name' dataAlign='center'headerAlign="center" width="60%" thStyle={ {fontWeight: 'lighter', marginLeft:'5px'}}>
        Name
</TableHeaderColumn>
 <TableHeaderColumn dataField='dateofBirth'dataAlign='center' headerAlign="right">
       Date of Birth
 </TableHeaderColumn>

    </BootstrapTable>
<br></br>
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
<label>
 ID:
 <input type="text" name="Id"  onChange={this.handleIDChange} />
 </label>
 <label>
 Name:
 <input type="text" name="name"  onChange={this.handleNameChange}/>
   </label>
 <label>
 Date of Birth
  <input type="text" name="birth" onChange={this.handleBirthChange}/>
 </label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
  </div>
```

this is my code i want to insert data after next to three rows..how i can do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/a/49785510/1502207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
handleSubmit(event) {

  console.log('A ID:name and birth was submitted: ' + 
    this.state.Id,this.state.Name,this.state.birth);
  event.preventDefault();

  const { id, name, dateofBirth } = this.state;    
  const newObj = {
    id: id,
    name: name,
    dateofBirth: dateofBirth 
  };

  console.log("prevState");
  console.log(prevState);
  console.log(newState);
  console.log([...prevState.data, newObj]);
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    data: [...prevState.data, newObj ]
  }));

}
```

Comment: can u explain it properly ??i cannt get it properly

Comment: I assume that in handleSubmit you have id, name, dateofBirth, in the state, right? Then the above code takes these values, creats newObj that has these values, and sets the states so that the array in the state gets the newObj as last array element...

Comment: const { id, name, dateofBirth } = this.state;    
const newObj = {
 id: id,
 name: name,
 dateofBirth: dateofBirth 
};the id,name and date of birth and the name,id,and dateofbirth in obects are same ??

Comment: you ask to create new object for id,name and dateofbirth??this object for that value which i get from input box ?

Comment: Yes. Just to have an object that will be used in the call to setState in my answer

Comment: can u please update my code which i post in question ???please i submit to boss after 30 mins :(please

Comment: I did. I think that you need to update the handleSubmit function and I wrote in my answer the updated code for this function

Comment: i used push function like as  this.setState(prevState => ({
          data: [prevState.data.push(newdata) ]
        })); when i console it shows me new data in array but cannt shows data in my table

Comment: Did you try instead the code that I suggested? Push is not good since you are mutating prevState.

Comment: yeah i tried but after your code i used only 1 time new row is genrated and my previous rows vanished from table

Comment: Added console.log() calls. Please add the output to the end of your question.